# How to use NTILE function to create two groups for two columns where one is a nested NTILE of the other?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have financial data that I want to categorise (using `NTILE()`) by two columns that contain percentage values (`risk`, `debt_to_assets`). My end goal is that I want to aggregate some other column (`profit`) by the two categories, but that's not related to my issue at hand. The data looks something like this:

| profit | risk | debt_to_assets |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7000 | 0.10 | 0.20 |
| 1000 | 0.40 | 0.70 |
| 3000 | 0.15 | 0.50 |
| 4000 | 0.30 | 0.30 |
| 2000 | 0.20 | 0.60 |

The issue I'm trying to solve is that I want the categories to be nested such that, in addition to the population distribution being uniform, the categories of the inner quantile are consistent across the categories of the outer quantile in terms of the range that defines the categories (i.e. I want the min and max value for the inner categories *(x0, y0), (x1, y0), (x2, y0), ...* to all be the same or as close as possible, where the *x*'s are the outer category and the *y*'s are the inner category).

Ideally if I were to aggregate the columns used for the `NTILE()` function (using 3 inner categories and 3 outer categories for example) I'd want a table that resembles the following:

| risk_cat | dta_cat | min_risk | max_risk | min_dta | max_dta | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.00 | 0.33 | 0.00 | 0.33 | 100 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.00 | 0.33 | 0.34 | 0.67 | 100 |
| 1 | 3 | 0.00 | 0.33 | 0.68 | 1.00 | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | 0.34 | 0.67 | 0.00 | 0.33 | 100 |
| 2 | 2 | 0.34 | 0.67 | 0.34 | 0.67 | 100 |
| 2 | 3 | 0.34 | 0.67 | 0.68 | 1.00 | 100 |
| 3 | 1 | 0.68 | 1.00 | 0.00 | 0.33 | 100 |
| 3 | 2 | 0.68 | 1.00 | 0.34 | 0.67 | 100 |
| 3 | 3 | 0.68 | 1.00 | 0.68 | 1.00 | 100 |

These are the solutions I've tried but they only solve part of the issue, not the whole thing:

```
SELECT *,
    NTILE(3) OVER (
        ORDER BY risk
    ) AS risk_cat,
    NTILE(3) OVER (
        ORDER BY debt_to_assets
    ) AS dta_cat
FROM my_table
```

This would result in an aggregated table like this:

| risk_cat | dta_cat | min_risk | max_risk | min_dta | max_dta | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.00 | 0.33 | 0.00 | 0.33 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.00 | 0.33 | 0.34 | 0.67 | 55 |
| 1 | 3 | 0.00 | 0.33 | 0.68 | 1.00 | 180 |
| 2 | 1 | 0.34 | 0.67 | 0.00 | 0.33 | 135 |
| 2 | 2 | 0.34 | 0.67 | 0.34 | 0.67 | 140 |
| 2 | 3 | 0.34 | 0.67 | 0.68 | 1.00 | 100 |
| 3 | 1 | 0.68 | 1.00 | 0.00 | 0.33 | 130 |
| 3 | 2 | 0.68 | 1.00 | 0.34 | 0.67 | 110 |
| 3 | 3 | 0.68 | 1.00 | 0.68 | 1.00 | 40 |

The problem is that the count across the two categories isn't uniform.

```
WITH outer_cat AS (
    SELECT *,
        NTILE(3) OVER (
            ORDER BY risk
        ) AS risk_cat
    FROM my_table
)
SELECT *,
    NTILE(3) OVER(
        PARTITION BY risk_cat
        ORDER BY debt_to_assets
    ) AS dta_cat
FROM outer_cat
```

The aggregated table for this might resemble the following:

| risk_cat | dta_cat | min_risk | max_risk | min_dta | max_dta | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.00 | 0.33 | 0.10 | 0.70 | 100 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.00 | 0.33 | 0.71 | 0.90 | 100 |
| 1 | 3 | 0.00 | 0.33 | 0.91 | 1.00 | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | 0.34 | 0.67 | 0.05 | 0.35 | 100 |
| 2 | 2 | 0.34 | 0.67 | 0.36 | 0.60 | 100 |
| 2 | 3 | 0.34 | 0.67 | 0.61 | 0.90 | 100 |
| 3 | 1 | 0.68 | 1.00 | 0.00 | 0.25 | 100 |
| 3 | 2 | 0.68 | 1.00 | 0.26 | 0.50 | 100 |
| 3 | 3 | 0.68 | 1.00 | 0.51 | 0.80 | 100 |

The problem this time is that the min and max values for the inner category vary to much across the outer category.

```
SELECT *,
    NTILE(9) OVER(
        ORDER BY risk, debt_to_assets
    ) AS dual_cat
FROM my_table
```

The aggregated table for this looks something like the following:

| dual_cat | min_risk | max_risk | min_dta | max_dta | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.00 | 0.11 | 0.55 | 1.00 | 100 |
| 2 | 0.12 | 0.22 | 0.35 | 1.00 | 100 |
| 3 | 0.23 | 0.33 | 0.15 | 1.00 | 100 |
| 4 | 0.34 | 0.44 | 0.40 | 1.00 | 100 |
| 5 | 0.45 | 0.55 | 0.10 | 1.00 | 100 |
| 6 | 0.56 | 0.66 | 0.10 | 0.95 | 100 |
| 7 | 0.67 | 0.77 | 0.05 | 1.00 | 100 |
| 8 | 0.78 | 0.88 | 0.20 | 1.00 | 100 |
| 9 | 0.89 | 1.00 | 0.00 | 1.00 | 100 |

This was just a last attempt at a solution after the previous two didn't work. This attempt didn't capture any of the behaviour that I was looking for.

Is there a solution to my problem that I'm not seeing?

Comment: I don't really understand your problems. *"The problem is that the count across the two categories isn't uniform."* - Well yes, you have non-uniform distribution within your data so you would expect this. What you are doing is a measure of the distribution, so expecting perfect distribution is unreasonable. *"The problem this time is that the min and max values for the inner category vary to much across the outer category."* - Again yes, this shows that there is likely correlation between your two categories, the lower the risk the higher the dta.

Comment: Both of your first two approaches are perfectly valid and are giving you good insight into the data, if you ended up with the results you are after, all that would tell you is that you have a perfectly uniform data set with no correlation between the two categories.

Comment: @GarethD yeah, I was already thinking that I was trying to fit a square peg in a round hole. I just tried asking the question here as a last resort to see if what I wanted to achieve is possible. As I mentioned at the very beginning, my ultimate goal was to aggregate another variable by the categories and create a matrix where the cells are the aggregate values and the row and column bounds are determine by the two categories. I thought it would be better if the count in each cell was uniform, hence the question.

Comment: Yeah, I'd definitely agree with the square peg, round hole analogy. You can either have uniform bandings with non-uniform distribution, or uniform distribution with non-uniform bandings. But not both. I think the non-uniform distribution is the better insight, it would allow you to do a heat map, or bubble chart or similar to show the non-uniformity (or uniformity depending on your actual data)